# When using a setState function from useState as argument in useEffect why it is not required to write a callBack

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I use a function from my component in the useEffect arguments as I understand I should write a callBack so it is memorized and used as dependency of the useEffect otherwise there is a warning, but when I use the setState of useState why there is no need to write a callback. Is it memorized by default? How does setState of useState work differently then a method in my component?

```
const [username, setUsername] = useState(undefined)
const [password, setPassword] = useState(undefined)

const onSuccessfulLogin  = useCallback((data, token) => {
    setUsername('')
    setPassword('')
    setUser(data)
    setAuth(token)
},[setUsername, setPassword])

useEffect(() => {
    onSuccessfulLogin()
},[onSuccessfulLogin])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I use the setState of useState why there is no need to write a callback

Because it's guaranteed to return a stable function reference between renders. And the rules of hooks lint plugin knows that, so it lets you omit it from the dependency array.

Comment: But when the setter is passed as props from the parent there is a warning for missing dependency, in this case should I write explicit callback  or can I use the setter from the props directly?

Comment: There is no need to wrap useCallback around a single state setter. The state setter is already a stable reference. The lint plugin can't always tell what's stable and what's not, so if you know better than the plugin, you can use `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` to disable the plugin.